# codeigniter join table ss

Tags: codeigniter, join

I have a problem with codeigniter,
I want to do a join in the addition of a carrier,
when I add I assign a truck this driver
I want the state of truck changes from 0 to 1,
but I do not know,

```
public function add($email, $password , $nom , $prenom , $telephone,$id_camion)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('transporteur', array('email' => $email));

    if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->db->insert('transporteur', array('email' => $email,'password' => md5($password),'nom' => $nom ,'prenom'=>$prenom   ,'telephone' => $telephone,'id_camion' => $id_camion)); 

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, now that you've inserted a new carrier you want to set some `state` in a table of trucks. You already have the truck ID as a parameter so in theory all you need to do is:

```
//update only on a given camion_id
$this->db->where('id', $camion_id);
$this->db->update('camions', array('state' => 1));
```

Here I assume your table is called `camions`, its ID is `id` and the state column you're trying to change from 0 to 1 is called `state`.

If that's not quite right, please update your question. If you have trouble translating it into english, I can help with that, too. ;)

Comment: thank you WereWolf and SolarBear 
 SolarBear , your solution is great boss :) thank you very much

Comment: excuse me i would like with this "state" affected 0 when i delete the transporteur then the camion will be free. 
i added the same code but any change .

Comment: public function delete($email)
    {
        $uid = $this->db->get_where('transporteur', array('email' => $email))->row()->tid;
        $this->db->delete('transporteur', array('email' => $email));
        

    }

Comment: I know nothing about your database schema, I'm afraid. The way I understand it, though, you need to find all `camions` linked to that `transporteur`. Get all of their ids in an array, for instance, then `$this->db->where_in('id', $camion_ids)->update('camions', array('state', 0))` where `$camion_ids` would hold all your IDs.

Comment: no SolarBear one transporteur is with one camion 
so when i add a transporteur with his camion we need to add 1 to the state but when i delete this transporteur i need to update the state to 0 , the camion will be free

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your question but you have (`num_rows` should be `num_rows()`) following code:

```
if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

It should be:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

It's a method not a property. You may also use it like this way:

```
if ($query->num_rows()) {
    return FALSE;
}
```